# Math Quiz VB 2010 Odd Crash

Tags: vb.net, math

I have an issue with my Math quiz on VB 2010. When I input an incorrect number the program crashes. Can anyone help. I have edited the code so that there is no errors and visually it looks fine but I'm currently an a bit of trouble. Thanks Here's my code

[The crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAmIh.png)

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If TextBox1.Text = String.Empty Then
        MsgBox("Please type your asnswer :)")
    ElseIf Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then
        MsgBox("This is not a valid number.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End If

    userAnswer = TextBox1.Text

    If userAnswer = numZ Then
        MsgBox("Correct. Proceed to the next question")
        score = score + 1
    Else
        MsgBox("Sorry this answer is incorrect. THe correct answer is " + numZ)
    End If

    Turn2.Text = turn
    turn = turn + 1

    If turn < 10 Then
        numA.Text = (num1.Next(1, 10))
        numB.Text = (num2.Next(1, 10))
        sim = (sim1.Next(1, 4))


        numX = numA.Text
        numY = numB.Text

        Select Case sim
            Case 1
                SimZ.Text = "+"
                numZ = numX + numY
            Case 2
                SimZ.Text = "X"
                numZ = numX * numY
            Case 3
                SimZ.Text = "-"
                numZ = numX - numY
        End Select
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Your score is " + score + " out of ten")
        Me.Close()
    End If



End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

`+` on a `Double` and a `String` in VB.Net tries to convert the string to a number. Just call `ToString` on `numZ` (and use `&` for concatenation, as it doesn't do funky conversions)

The error is [clearly documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9c5t70w2.aspx).

Comment: Yep. I don't know how many times I've told users here _**to not**_ concatenate strings with the `+` operator. :D